# RegEx pattern to get text surrounded with quotes that ends with backslash

Tags: regex

I am using this regex pattern `([""'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1` to grap text surrounded with quotes in a text file. And it worked. But it failed to work for text that ends with \

For example, i have the following content:

```
This is a group of "text file" that i want to "get texts" which are surrounded by quotes. 
But "it failed\" to get text that ends with backslash
```

The above regex pattern will get:

`"text file", "get texts"`

But it won't get `"it failed\"`

My question now is, how do i modify the above regex pattern to get text surrounded with quotes that ends with a backslash?

Comment: Then just use `(["'])(.*?)\1` or `(["'])((?:(?!\1).)*?)\1`

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks so much